# product page urls changed after upgrade

Tags: magento2.3, product-urls

I have upgraded magento from 2.1.8 EE to 2.3.1 EE. After upgrade the product page urls have changed, 
they should be in the format-  https://site-url/parent-category/sub-category/product-name.html  whereas they are rendering as - https://site-url/catalog/product/view/id/138/s/product-name/category/6/

Please provide a solution.

Comment: Currently, I have no proper solution for that case. In the past, I tried with this extension: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Comment: used the above extension, regenerated product urls but still the product urls are rendering as  https://site-url/catalog/product/view/id/138/s/product-name/category/6/

Comment: Hello, Please provide a solution about how to rewrite product pages urls from catalog/product/view/id/ to category/subacategory/productname/ using the above extension.